# Error: Undefined Main but it's right there

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, cs50

SOLUTION: I'm working on a different computer and logged in the try some of these solutions. It just started working. Not sure if different computer but I've clearly got some learning to do.

I put in the following and the error message comes up that there is no main. I'm starting out in CS50 so I don't know if it's some kind of bug or I'm just being dumb. Also the first time I'm using an IDE instead of a sandbox.

Doesn't work trying to do Hello World either, I get the same error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
    {
        string name = get_string ("Name: \n");
        printf ("Hello, %s\n", name);
    } 

~/workspace/ $ make hello
clang -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    hello.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o hello
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

Comment: What's the name of your file? What is in your Makefile?

Comment: Can you remove the include of cs50.h? And remove the call to get_string? I'm curious if that header fall is causing it.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, then it seems odd that you're trying to build the project from the command line.  Building from the command line should be *possible*, to be sure, but an IDE does not necessarily set things up in a way that makes command-line building easy.

Comment: The bug is in one of the libraries that you are liking. Get rid of crypt, m and cs50.build will work, then add them back in one by one.

Comment: I doubt it's the libraries -- adding a library would not remove a symbol.   It could be that `cs50.h` has some bad symbols at the end of it, causing the compiler to misparse the main function, but I can't imagine anything that wouldn't cause any other type of error.   The most likely scenerio is that you have some hidden characters around `main (void)`.   Try wiping out the the line, and manually typing it in again.     Also, double check that you're compiling hello.c from the directory you think you're compiling it from (if it picks up a different hello.c, it might not have a `main`...)

Comment: Open cs50.h in your text editor and verify that the last line still says #endif.